# Registration validation doesn't work properly

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, isset

I have registration form, with "username" and "password".

```
 <form  method="post" onSubmit="return check();" name="Reg">    
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="sign-up-input" maxlength="30" placeholder="Username" >
        <input type="password" class="sign-up-input" name="Password" id="Password" maxlength="25" placeholder="Password" >
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up" name="signup"  class="sign-up-button" onClick="time_get()">
 </form>
```

After I enter values for "password" and "username", I want to check wheter those values are valid. First I want to check if the user entered values for "email" and "password", after the user press the "signup" button.

```
 if(isset($_POST['signup']))
 {
            $error_text="";
            $check_val=1;
            if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']))
            {
                //area 1 
                //entered values for email and password
                $email_signup=$_POST['email'];
                $password_signup=$_POST['password'];
                //more code....
            }
            else
            {
                //area 2
                //email or password are empty
                $check_val=0;
                $error_id=1;
            }
  }
```

For after I enter valid values for "email" and "password", and then press the "sign-up" button, it enter to "area 2", meaning that at least one value(email/password) is empty.

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: I think you have a case sensitive issue. You used Password on input with capital P
    <input type="password" class="sign-up-input" name="Password" id="Password" maxlength="25" placeholder="Password" >

but used simple p on

    isset($_POST['password'])

Comment: change your line to this $password_signup=$_POST['Password'];

Comment: Please tell me you're not storing plain text passwords.